# What is the exact meaning of match_parent?

Tags: android-layout

I just want to check my understanding is right. In android studio, layout attributes there are layout_width, layout_height. I know both of them as Widget / Layout 's width and height. and we can assign match_parent there. According to my understanding, match_parent always means the widget's height/width is same as the Activity's.

Is my understanding correct??

Answer (score 1):

Match parent means.  The widget you're assigning let's suppose height then it'll require the same height as the parent widget /layout 
For example if i give 420dp height to my linearlayout and then inside it i provide an imagview as match parent then it's gonna have the same height as linear layout

Answer (score 0):

`match_parent` is a constant value for views to stretch according to their parents or.

let's say there is a `RelativeLayout` in your layout XML, whatever widget (`View`) you put in your root view would stretch according to the parent (which is root view or `RelativeLayout` in our case).